# ASP data list is adding a blank row inbetween each row with data

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, datalist

This is my front end code here:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped1 table-hover">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr class="thead">
            <th scope="col">one</th>
            <th scope="col">two</th>
            <th scope="col">three</th>
            <th scope="col">four</th>
            <th scope="col">five</th>
            <th scope="col">six</th>
            <th scope="col">seven</th>
            <th scope="col">eight</th>
            <th scope="col">nine</th>
            <th scope="col">ten</th>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date")%>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbOrderNo" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OrderLink")%>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OrderNo")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPO" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PO")%>'> </asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblInvoiceNo" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Invoices")%>'> </asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLines" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Lines")%>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="Price">$<asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Total")%>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>'> </asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSource" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Via")%>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblShipper" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Shipped")%>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbTracking" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "blank")%>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Tracking")%> </asp:LinkButton></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

[image: 1st error]

^this is whats showing up on my website

[image: 2nd error]

^this is the extra row thats being made

Did I make an error in my code or do you think this is a database problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the way a DataList generates html. It creates it's own table. And the Header and Item Template automatically get a `<tr><td> </td></tr>` in which the contents is rendered.

Because you are also adding a `<tr>`, it becomes nested and that is invalid html. This is what you are creating:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      //start template content
      <tr>
         <td>

         </td>
      </tr>
      //end template content
   </td>
</tr>
```

If you are creating a table, start using a GridView. Or if you want to generate your own table structure, a Repeater.